# Grails Hibernate version upgrade

Tags: hibernate, grails

The latest version of Grails(2.1.1) does not support the latest vesion of Hibernate(4.1.7)

It support the version 2.1.1 by default.

What is to be done for upgrading Hibernate in Grails 2.1.1 ?

Comment: I don't think there's anyway to upgrade the underlying hibernate dependencies for GORM

Comment: The version 2.1.1 is of the hibernate plugin for grails, not hibernate itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of Grails (currently 2.2.0.RC1) supports Hibernate 3.6. The version 2.2.1 that you are referring to is the version of the Hibernate plugin, which matches the version of Grails.

You can't upgrade the version of Hibernate used by Grails. It's on the [development roadmap](http://grails.org/Roadmap) for Grails 2.3.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Grails 2.1.1 and Grails Hibernate Plugin 2.1.1 as well.

As others have said, the version of the Grails Hibernate Plugin is 2.1.1 and it corresponds to your version of Grails 2.1.1.

If you are interested in seeing the exact dependencies of the Grails Hibernate Plugin 2.1.1, you can open up `dependencies.groovy` in your .grails folder:

```
/home/<user>/.grails/2.1.1/projects/<your_project>/plugins/hibernate-2.1.1/
```

Here you will see the exact Hibernate Core version upon which Grails Hibernate 2.1.1 Plugin depends upon.  I did this, and here are the Hibernate dependencies of this Plug-in (I omitted others like ANTLR and the excludes):

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.10.Final') {
        ....
    }
    compile( 'org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final' ){
        ....
    }

    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.1.0.Final') {
        ....
    }
    runtime('org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:3.6.10.Final') {
        ....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.2.3 supports Hibernate 4!